# G sheet: display empty column content in a pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a resourcing pivot table that shows the sum of roles by Status (Onboarding, Active, Vacant)
linked to a chart.

If I only have Active, Vacant resources in the main table, in the pivot I am not able to see also column "Onboarding" with empty or 0 value,

So if a resource changes a status from Vacant to Onboarding, I have to manually change the chart range and add the new serie

This is the actual status pivot:

[image]

This is the desired pivot

[image]

Question: how can I add all the status even if empty ( if possible put zero instead of empty)
I m trying to avoid any manual intervention as it should be maintained by someone else.

Thank you in advance.
Regards.

Comment: This looks similar to these answered posts [Show empty columns in pivot table](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/110447277/show-empty-columns-in-pivot-table?hl=en&msgid=111196556) & [Google sheets pivot table: show items with no data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41864917/15384825)

Comment: Hi @IrvinJayG. the title is similar but the solution is not what I look for as in my example the status of each row ( for example ETL Dev) may change during the recruitment process from Vacant to onboarding to active. So I cannot add empty row so my original file looks not clean especially that's a dynamic file where people can edit everyday